# Unrecognized token 'Payment': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

Tags: java, spring, jackson, postman, h2

I am developing two Spring Boot microservices (order and payment) using H2 database order microservice calls the payment service through `RestTemplate` whenever I book an order using postman the payment service is called successfully and data is stored in the payment DB but not in the order service and I am receiving the above error:

**here is my code**

**service**

```java
public TransactionResponse saveOrder(TransactionRequest request) {
    String responseMessage = "";
    Order order = request.getOrder();
    Payment payment = request.getPayment();
    payment.setOrderId(order.getId());
    payment.setAmount(order.getPrice());
    // response message
    System.out.println(order);
    // rest api call to payment service
    Payment paymentResponse =
           restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8082/api/payment", payment, Payment.class);

    responseMessage = paymentResponse.getPaymentStatus().equals("success")?
           "payment processed successfully": "payment failed ";
    orderRepository.save(order);
    System.out.println(paymentResponse);

    return new TransactionResponse(order , paymentResponse.getTransactionId() , paymentResponse.getAmount(), responseMessage);
}
```

**Controller**

```java
@PostMapping
public TransactionResponse bookOrder(@RequestBody TransactionRequest transactionRequest) {
    return orderService.saveOrder(transactionRequest);
}
```

****Transaction Request model****

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TransactionRequest  {
  private Order order;
  private Payment payment;
}
```

****payment model****

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Payment {
    private int paymentId;
    private String paymentStatus;
    private String transactionId;
    private double amount;
    private int orderId;
}
```

**images**

[image: the error iam recieving]

[image: postman request]

Comment: Should be your request an array of objects ? [..] instead of {..} ?

Comment: Share your code for TransactionRequest  model

Comment: Can you please add `Payment` code to your question? Additionally, the Postman shows `http://localhost:8082/api/order` and your code `http://localhost:8082/api/payment`. Please clarify your question. Thanks!

Comment: @mystery i ve added the transactionRequest model to the question

Comment: @JoãoDias  let me clarify the end points here  order service is running on port : 8081 , localhost:8081/api/order is the main api whichs responsible book orders and then its calls the payment api which is running on port : 8082 , localhost:8082/api/payment NOTE : i ve added the payment code to the question

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: @mystery when ever i do http request to http://localhost:8081/api/order through postman

Comment: I copy and paste your exact code but found no error

Comment: Can you also add `Order` class? Additionally, do you get this error while deserializing your POST request body into `TransactionRequest` in `public TransactionResponse bookOrder`? Is that it?

Comment: @JoãoDias  thanks broi figured out my self i will post the answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh I got the problem since I was doing rest api call to the payment service the post method of the payment service was returning string instead of Payment object.

**this was my post payment method before:**

```java
@PostMapping
public String orderPayment(@RequestBody Payment payment) {
   paymentService.doPayment(payment);
   return "Payment done";
}
```

**this is what is how it is supposed to be**

```java
@PostMapping
public Payment orderPayment(@RequestBody Payment payment) {
   return paymentService.doPayment(payment);
}
```

note: the return type

Comment: Now you understand why it is so important to add ALL relevant code to your questions ;)

Comment: @JoãoDias yes thanks for ur help man

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer so that your question can be "closed" ;) Thanks!

Comment: its giving me 20 hours to accept its i will surely do that